# How to calculate Big-O?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

```
public long seriesLoop() {
    long answer = a;        
    for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {          
        long delta = a;             
        for (long j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            delta *= r;             
        }           
        answer += delta;        
    }       
    return answer;  
}

public long seriesClosedForm() {
    return (long) (a * (1 - Math.pow(r, n)) / (1 - r));     
}
```

What is the Big-O notation for these 2 methods?
Why? How do we calculate the big-O of an algorithm?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework dump.

Comment: you calculate big O according to loops . one loop = O(n). nested loop = O(n^2)

Comment: @j.pei kindly read this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it). This will give you clear idea of Big O.

Comment: `O(...)` is worst-case.  Each loop gives a factor of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first method, it is n*n = n^2. Since there are two loops, for each loop 
O(n) is n since you are going through each item in an array.

Second one is a constant o(1).

Comment: Yes, it's my answer. But my tutor said the first one should be O(n), and the second one actually is not O(1), it is O(log n).  I don't know why..